# How call event in correct way in Module Pattern edition

Tags: structure

After reading an article https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/ I did something similar in my project - created the structure:

```js
var SomeStructure = {

 
 var1: $('#tag1'),
 
 init: function() {
  
  this.var1.on('click', function (e) {
   SomeStructure.mouseClick(e);
  });
    },
    mouseClick: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("tag clicked");
    }
  
 }

SomeStructure.init();
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag1">Click me!</div>
```

My code is working, but I wondering if it's possible rewrite the code:

`this.var1.on('click', function (e) {
                SomeStructure.mouseClick(e);
            });`

so that the call of function mouseClick after clicking the $('#tag1') in some more neat way without anonymous function in one row, something like that:
`this.var1.on('click', this.mouseClick);`

But this way isn't right without e..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add a new function ListenEvents for events listening, so that a lot of new listeners could be added inside to make clear workflow object (as described here http://derickbailey.com/2015/08/07/making-workflow-explicit-in-javascript/) :

`var SomeStructure = {
    var1: $('#tag1'),
    init: function() {
        this.ListenEvents();

```
},
ListenEvents: function() {
    self = SomeStructure;
    self.var1.on('click', self.mouseClick);
},
mouseClick: function() {
  alert("tag clicked");
}
```

}

SomeStructure.init();`